# How to bring Arrow in Extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have to draw two components(2 Circles) in a panel and I have to connect those 2 draw components(2 circles) using arrow(`---->`, `<----`), I don't know how to do in Extjs4.

Answer (score 1):

Check [drawing and charting](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/drawing_and_charting) tutorial in the documentation.